# Transform an option list into stars

Tags: html, css

I'm using this part of code to rate some articles that i formed from MySQL. Rate is done my an option list where someone can rate them with numbers 1,2,3. It is possible to transform somehow this list into 3 stars (with radio buttons, images or something)?

```
<form id="ratethis-<?=$PK?>" action="rate.php?idP=<?=$idPK?>"method="post">
 <select name="rating">

 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 </select> <br> 
 <input type="submit" value="Rate this!"/><br><br>
 </form>
```

Comment: Look at these : http://kubyshkin.ru/posts/star-rating-input-pure-css.html http://css-tricks.com/star-ratings/  http://www.danielkeithjones.com/Articles/Web_Development/Pure_CSS_5_Star_Rating_System_with_Radios/

Answer (score 2):

On html:

```
<ul class="rating">
<span class="strong"><strong><li class="one"><a href="#">1 Star</a></li></strong></span>
<span class="strong"><strong><li class="two"><a href="#">2 Stars</a></li></strong></span>
<span class="strong"><strong><li class="three"><a href="#">3 Stars</a></li></strong></span>
<span class="strong"><strong><li class="four"><a href="#">4 Stars</a></li></strong></span>
<span class="strong"><strong><li class="five"><a href="#">5 Stars</a></li></strong></span>
</ul>
```

On CSS:

```
.rating {

margin: 0;

padding: 0;

list-style: none;

clear: both;

width: 75px;

height: 15px;

background-image: url(stars.gif);

background-repeat: no-repeat;

position: relative;

}

.rating li {

text-indent: −9999em;

float: left; /* for IE6 */

}

.rating li a {

position: absolute;

top: 0;

left: 0;

z-index: 20;

height: 15px;

width: 15px;

display: block;

}

.rating .one a {

left: 0;

}

.rating .two a {

left: 15px;

}

.rating .three a {

left: 30px;

}

.rating .four a {

left: 45px;

}

.rating .five a {

left: 60px;

}
```

Maybe this link could be helpful:

[How to create a star ranking system using css](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1007-how-to-create-a-star-ranking-system-using-css/)

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon here on SO. You should post relevant code snippets from that article within your answer and appropriately cite them.

Comment: Oh sorry, new on this. I thought it would be useless to copy & paste. Editting.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah sure, options are numerous:

1. Just use oldskool links:

   ```
   <a href="rate.php?idP=<?php echo $idPK; ?>&rating=1"><img src="star.jpg" /></a>
   <a href="rate.php?idP=<?php echo $idPK; ?>&rating=2"><img src="star.jpg" /></a>
   <a href="rate.php?idP=<?php echo $idPK; ?>&rating=3"><img src="star.jpg" /></a>
   ```

   Make sure you get the rating from `$_GET` instead of `$_POST` though
2. Use javascript (jquery in this example):

   ```
   <img src="star.gif" class="rating" rel="1" />
   <img src="star.gif" class="rating" rel="1" />
   <img src="star.gif" class="rating" rel="1" />

   $('.rating').on('click', function() {
       $.post('rate.php?idP=<?php echo $idPK; ?>', {rating: $(this).attr('rel') }, function() { alert('rating saved'); }
   });
   ```
3. Be creative and post some code